# can any one explain me behaviour of the perl program

Tags: perl, logical-operators

```
$a="";
$b="n";
$c = !$a;
$d = !$b;
print $c , "\n" , $d;
if($d == 0){
    print "zero";
}
```

I wrote this perl program i expected the output to be as follows

```
1  
0Zero
```

but it prints

```
1  
zero
```

can any one explain me why is it like that??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variables in Perl are treated as either numbers or strings depending on the context.  If you haven't treated something as a number when assigning to it, Perl will treat it like a string when you print it.

Because of this, false values are [a bit different in Perl than in languages with stronger typing](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Truth-and-Falsehood) (emphasis added by me):

> The number 0, the strings '0' and "" , the empty list () , and undef
>   are all false in a boolean context. All other values are true.
>   *Negation of a true value by ! or not returns a special false value.
>   When evaluated as a string it is treated as "" , but as a number, it
>   is treated as 0.* Most Perl operators that return true or false behave
>   this way.

So, the issue here is that `!` is a *logical* operator rather than an arithmetic one.  Therefore, it returns a *logically false* value, which is represented in different ways depending on the context.

If you want to make sure something is treated as a number, you have a few options.  You can perform an arithmetic operation, which will make Perl consider the result a number:

```
$d=!$b+0;
print $d;
```

You can use `sprintf` or `printf` to explicitly control the display:

```
printf '%d', $d;
```

Or you can use `int`:

```
print int $d;
```

(Note: this all may seem a bit complicated.  But it was designed so that the language will just do what you want, and you won't have to think about it.  And normally it does.  There are only occasional edge cases where you need to do something other than Perl's default behavior.)

Comment: but why it is not printing 0 for $d

Comment: Because `$d` contains an empty string, not zero. The way to force a numerical interpretation is to say `0+$d`.

Comment: And the meaning of `!` is basically "1 if the operand is not zero or an empty string; otherwise, the empty string". This is mildly surprising but consistent with how boolean truth is defined in Perl.

Comment: @nikhilmehta, more detail added.

Answer (score 2):

`!$b` evaluates to empty string `''`, as false values are not represented by zero when stringified by `print()`, `"$bool"`, or some other string operation.

```
$a="";
$b="n";
$c = !$a;
$d = !$b;
print $c , "\n" , $d;
if($d == 0){
    print "zero";
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper {
  '$a' => $a,
  '$b' => $b,
  '$c' => $c,
  '$d' => $d,
  '$d == 0' => $d == 0,
};
```

output

```
$VAR1 = {
      '$d == 0' => 1,  # boolean true
      '$b' => 'n',
      '$d' => '',      # boolean false
      '$c' => 1,
      '$a' => ''
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

In [perlsyn, under Truth and Falsehood](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Truth-and-Falsehood) you read

> The number 0, the strings '0' and "" , the empty list () , and undef are all false in a boolean context. All other values are true. Negation of a true value by ! or not returns a special false value. When evaluated as a string it is treated as "" , but as a number, it is treated as 0. Most Perl operators that return true or false behave this way.

This is what you experience. `$a` is false value, so `!$a`, assigned to `$c`, becomes a true value, accordingly printed as `1`. `$b` is a true value, so `!$b`, assigned to `$d`, becomes that special false value. In the print statement (`print $c , "\n" , $d;`), it is evaluated in string context, so the empty string is printed. The if statement (`$d == 0`) evaluates it in number context, so it is a `0`, hence `zero` is printed.

Answer (score 1):

Perl operators such as `!` that return boolean values return a special value for false: it is "" when used in string context and 0 when used in numeric context.

So when you print it, it is "", not "0".  But if you try to use it as a number, it doesn't give a warning the way "" does.  Compare:

```
perl -wle'$false = !1; print "string: ", $false, " number: ", 0+$false'
string:  number: 0
```

and

```
perl -wle'$empty = ""; print "string: ", $empty, " number: ", 0+$empty'
Argument "" isn't numeric in addition (+) at -e line 1.
string:  number: 0
```